# Cannot convert from double to class

Tags: java

I have a class named Complex that stores real and imaginary numbers. I have to include a constant of the Complex class that represents this, however, it does not compile due to mismatch of cannot convert double to Complex.

I am new to Java and am wondering how can I fix this and please explain why so I can learn.

```
public final class Complex {
    public static final Complex ONE = 1.0 + 0.0 * Math.sqrt(-1);
    public static final Complex I = 0.0 + 1.0 * Math.sqrt(-1);
    private double re;
    private double im;
}
```

Comment: Is there more code in your `Complex` class? You can't construct an object the way you are trying to.

Comment: `public static final Complex ONE = 1.0 + 0.0 * Math.sqrt(-1);` the right side  giving you `double` class, the left `Complex`, you cannot assign one class to another without a proper conversion (`casting`, `constructor` and such)

Comment: You want something like `I = new Complex(0, 1)` (and need to make a constructor shaped like that). You should also make `re` and `im` final (all other numbers in Java are immutable, for good reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public final class Complex {
    public static final Complex ONE = new Complex(1.0, 0.0);
    public static final Complex I = new Complex(0.0, 1.0);
    private double re;
    private double im;

    public Complex(double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    public Complex() {
    }

    public Complex(double re) {
        this.re = re;
    }
}
```

You need a constructor. And `Math.sqrt(-1)` is super.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you need a good understanding of how object constructors work in Java

There are a couple issues in the code sample you referenced, but I'll focus on what I *think* you're asking.

You want an instance of `Complex` initialized for a given random number. First, you would need to define what the `Complex` object looks like and *construct* it

```
public class Complex {
    private final double re;
    private final double im;

    public Complex(double real, double imaginary){
        this.re = real;
        this.im = imaginary;
    }
}
```

And then to *construct* an instance of the class you'd do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Complex complex = new Complex(1, 0);
    double realValue = complex.getRe(); // returns 1
    double imaginaryValue = complex.getIm(); //returns 0
}
```

Comment: The next thing you will want are `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` implementations, as well as some methods to do arithmetics with these `Complex` numbers.

Comment: Of course. I was just trying to get at what I perceived to be the original question: "How do I create an instance of `Complex`?" 
Did you interpret the question differently @Thilo?

Comment: No, your answer is great. My comment was aimed at @Keeley.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Thilo. Much appreciated